# Does anyone know why this session is not set in the next page?

Tags: php, session

I never really used session so it could be some stupid mistake. When I use if(isset($_SESSION) it outputs false, I think it has something to do with the foreach. I get no errors whatsoever. Could anyody spare some time to help me?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['register']))
    {
        require_once('../resources/library/register.class.php');
        //require_once('../resources/library/sessions.class.php');
        $obj_reg = new register();

        $name = $_POST['user'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $checking = $obj_reg->checking($name, $pass);


        //An foreach for converting POST data inside SESSION variables
        //isset checks if the array value contain post variables
        $posts = array($name, $pass, $email); 
        foreach ($posts as $p)
        {
            if(isset($_POST['p'])){
                    $_SESSION['p'] = $_POST['p'];

        }


        }
    }
    ?>

<form method="post" action="index.php?page=register.php">
    <table>
    <tr><td>username:</td><td> <input type="text" name="user"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>password:</td><td> <input type="password" name="pass"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td>email:</td><td> <input type="text" name="email"/></td></tr>
    <?=( !empty( $checking ) ) ? $checking : '' ?>
</table>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?=$token;?>"/>
    <input type="submit" name="register" value="register"/>
</form>
```

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['p']))
    {
        echo "mama";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "why?";
    }

?>
```

Comment: And where is your 'session_start' in the first script? You need to call it each time you access the session variables.

Comment: I did that, I accidentally didnt selected it as code

Comment: You are aware, that you don't HAVE a field named 'p', yes? Try checking for 'pass' instead of 'p' and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `session_start` on *every* page that needs `$_SESSION`.

I think you also mean to use `$_SESSION[$p] = $_POST[$p]` instead of the string `'p'`.

Comment: Also `$posts = array('user', 'pass', 'email');` makes more sense or you need a dynamic variable ($$p instead of $_POST[$p]). Else you iterate on POST values, not keys.